# How to make alarm sound using C?

Tags: c, audio, timer, notifications, libraries

I wanted to make a C program that could work as my Pomodoro Timer. I got the timer part and it is here

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){
    int sec;
    printf("\n Enter the no of minutes you need to wait :");
    scanf("%d",&sec);
    sec *= 60;
    do {
        printf("\r%d ",sec);
        sec--;
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }while(sec>0);

    printf("\n Time Elapsed");
    return 0;
}
```

I was just trying out the code and it works just fine, you could have 25 and 5 alternate for one cycle but that comes later. I thought it'd be nice if I am able to play some sort of sound or pass a notification but I don't think I know how to and I am scouring the internet as we speak searching for an answer but so far I am not able to find an appropriate answer. I promise to update this if at all I find the solution. If there is any particular library that I should be looking at please drop it off in the comments. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Printing a bell character will make it sound only once like just a Beep. If you wish to play a sound like Alarm, then you need to use some audio library and use some mp3 or wav file. You need to use the audio library for e.g. pulseaudio to make it play your mp3 or wav file, but also you cannot simply play mp3 or wav directly, you will need to convert them in .*h file for the C program to play them.
**If you want I can provide an example for you.**

Answer (score 1):

Windows Platform : [PlaySound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v%3Dvs.85))

```
PlaySound("Filename.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

Comment: Nice. Probably not relevant for OP, given the `#include <unistd.h>`, but have an upvote!

Comment: Thanks @jxh : Just didn't check the POSIX header file. added an answer for the Linux Platform.

Answer (score 0):

`\a` in a character constant or string denotes the audible bell.
<sub>[C Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape)</sub>

But, you might need to print a bunch of them to actually hear it.

---

As pointed out in comments, your terminal/console actually has to support doing something with the bell. I still use [*xterm*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm) on X11, which provides this option:

> **Enable Visual Bell (`visualbell`)**
>   Enable (or disable) visible bell (i.e., flashing) instead of  an  audible bell.
>   This corresponds to the `-vb` option and the `visualBell` resource.

Comment: The problem is that the terminal program has to support it.

Comment: @P__J__: No dispute. But since it is specifically called out in the C standard, it is very portable.

Comment: Windows does - just checked with VS19 console project.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Platform : [PulseAudio](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/index.html) or [SDL Audio](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sdl_loadwav) or [ALSA](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/)

PCM or WAV files can be handled by the above API to play the different types of Alarm tone.

Note : if you want to play .wav file in some case you need to handle the Wav header separately.